# How to create a Folder and read write restrict it, so that it could be open through my application only?

Tags: c#, wpf, directory

I have created a folder, now I want to restrict it so no one can read or write in it. This folder should be accessed by my application only. I can read, write in it through my application only. Actually I wanted to deploy a sandbox in my folder.

```
private void cFolder(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {

        if (!Directory.Exists(pathTextBox.Text + "\\" + nameTextBox.Text))
        {
            //main Folder
            Directory.CreateDirectory(pathTextBox.Text + "\\" + nameTextBox.Text);

            //drive name Folder
            string subdirectory = System.IO.Path.Combine(pathTextBox.Text + "\\" + nameTextBox.Text, "C");
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(subdirectory);

            //creating sub folders
            string subfolder1 = System.IO.Path.Combine(subdirectory, "Program Files");
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(subfolder1);
            string subfolder2 = System.IO.Path.Combine(subdirectory, "Program Files(x86)");
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(subfolder2);
            string subfolder3 = System.IO.Path.Combine(subdirectory, "Setup");
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(subfolder3);

            //Permissions call


            //next window
            applicationImport go = new applicationImport(pathTextBox.Text, nameTextBox.Text);
            this.Hide();
            go.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Directory Exists Already", "Error creating folder");
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error creating directory. Cannot Access Location");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know to restrict access to a folder is through NTFS permissions. This is per user, not per application, though. If you want the user to not be able to find the folder, you could put it in the user's AppData folder. This folder is hidden to most users, unless the Show Hidden Files and Folders option is selected and the Hide Protected Operating System Files (Recommended) option is deselected in the Folder Options dialog. To use it in C#, use `Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData` for the location. An example is below, using your code:

```
//creating sub folders
            string subfolder1 = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData,"MyApplication");
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(subfolder1);
            }
```

This will create a folder located at `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\MyApplication`
If the `Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData` won't work, you could try the other `Environment.SpecialFolder`locations. I don't know how to to this myself, but running the application in the context of a service account, instead of the user account might work and then assign permissions to the folder to that service account--see the following link https://superuser.com/questions/592216/restrict-access-to-a-folder-by-exe.